# Visual Basic - Random Number based on existing list of Numbers

Tags: vb.net, random

Currently I have the code below. it reads the file db.lcz line by line and puts each result into the array as an item.

In the db.lcz I have a 10 digit number on each line and I want to get a new random number based on the existing numbers from said file.

--

Any ideas are welcome, I have tried a few options but such as a for loop etc but I keep getting lost. I know I have to check each characters value against one another for the probability aspect but Im not sure how to continue. All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("db.lcz")
    Dim codeArray As New ArrayList()

    For x As Integer = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
        codeArray.Add(lines(x))
    Next
    For x = 0 To codeArray.Count - 1
        MsgBox(codeArray.Item(x))
    Next




    Dim rng As New Random
    Dim number As Integer = rng.Next(1, 1000000000)  'Test.GenerateDigits(rng, 9)
    Dim digits As String = number.ToString("0000000000")
    MsgBox(digits)
End Sub

Private Shared Function GenerateDigits(ByVal rng As Random, _
                 ByVal length As Integer) As String
    Dim chArray As Char() = New Char(length - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To length - 1
        chArray(i) = Convert.ToChar(rng.Next(10) + &H30)
    Next i
    Return New String(chArray)
End Function
```

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve is to pick a random number of a list of numbers then all you have to do is to generate a random index. For a list containing 8 numbers: `num = myList.Item(myRandom.Next(0, myList.Count))`

Comment: Nope, thanks anyways. My goal is to use the list of numbers to generate more numbers that are similar.

Comment: I have these 10 numbers below (some below) Using these numbers I want to generate similar numbers. A pattern kind of thing. Numbers: 6149910255, 7443200137, 7724264219, 7126553734, 5321570789, etc.

Comment: What is a "similar number"? What is your criteria for choosing a new number based on an existing set?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. To make a new number based on an existing set of numbers

Comment: I'm voting to close this as OP still has not demonstrated what he means by "a number based on existing numbers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shuffle function to reorder the digits randomly, with an index array.

```
s = "1234567890"
s1 = ""
ix = shuffle(s.Length - 1)
For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
  s1 &= s(ix(i))
  Next i
```

The shuffle function can be something similar to this:

```
Function shuffle(ByVal ncards As Integer) As List(Of Integer)

Dim rand As New Random
Dim ix As New List(Of Integer)
Dim k, n, tmp As Integer

For i as integer = 0 To ncards
  ix.Add(i)
  Next i

n = ncards
For i as integer = ncards To 1 Step -1
  k = rand.Next(1, n + 1)
  tmp = ix(i)
  ix(i) = ix(k)
  ix(k) = tmp
  Next i

Return ix

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry should of been more clear! My bad, The last line didnt seem to work. It generates the number but its definitely not based on the probability of the existing numbers. for example if the first character on every line is 7 then the first number generated should be a 7. however your answer generated a 1 instead of that. Thus making it not a viable solution. perhaps i put your code in at the wrong spot in my code. I put it in after the codearray.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. You want each new number to contain all the digits of the previous number, in a different order?

Comment: Sorry its hard to explain, I have a list of numbers in a text document. Each on a separate line and each number is 10 digits long. Now I want the program to open the document, then I want the program to go through all the lines and conduct the probability for each character/number (0-9) then I want it to generate a new number based on the probability. for example if 3 numbers (one on each line) are: 123 123 and 321 then the probability of the first character being a 1 is 66% the second character 100% etc. Thus the generated number would be 1 or 3 followed by 2 followed by a 3 or 1

Comment: Not sure how else to explain it other then basically I just an an algorithm to take a bunch of existing numbers and use those numbers to generate a new number over and over again.

Comment: I've edited the answer to do this. (Not sure if it's exactly what you're after.)

Comment: @CameronAndrews If the probability of the first character being a "1" is 66%, what are the probabilities of it being "0", "2".."9"?